# How can I change an numpy.ndarray into something that I can graph

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I am having trouble graphing a numpy.ndarray value. I don't have much experience so I may misname a few of these values. I believe it has to do with what type of class it is though.

Essentially I have a while loop that will take a video frame, average the pixels `average_int`, then graph the average pixels which creates a nice frequency of peaks. Then the average pixel value is appended to a `result_array` and goes through a peak detection function `signal.find_peaks_cwt`. After this I find the difference of the peaks `peaks_diff = peaks_pos[1:] - peaks_pos[:-1]` and use that as the frames between my peaks that I put into a formula that calculates beats per minute `frequency = 60000/(peaks_frames * 60)`.

Up to this point it seems to work rather well, and the next step was to create another graph to graph `frequency`. I copied the way I graphed `average_int` and it gives me this error: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`.

Here is my current while loop minus the graphing lines.
**EDIT**: Added the graphing code lines

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('cardiacbody.wmv')
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(varThreshold=21, detectShadows=False)


x_len = 60
y_range = [-2, 30]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(2,1,1)

xs = list(range(0,60))
ys = [0] * x_len
ys2 = [0] * x_len

result_array = np.array([0])

line, = ax.plot(xs, ys, color='k')
line2, = ax2.plot(xs, ys2, color='b')

ax.set_ylim(y_range)
ax2.set_ylim(y_range)

plt.title('Movement over Time')


def animate(i, ys):
    ys.append(average_int)
    ys = ys[-x_len:]
    line.set_ydata(ys)
    return line,

def animate2(i, ys2):
    ys2.append(frequency)
    ys2 = ys2[-x_len:]
    line2.set_ydata(ys2)
    return line2,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(ys,),interval=100, blit=False)
ani2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig2, animate2, fargs=(ys2,),interval=100, blit=False)



while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)

    cv2.imshow('Original', frame)
    cv2.imshow('Masked', fgmask)

    average = (np.average(fgmask))                                  # Average pixel intensity of frame

    average_int = int(average)                                      # Convert average into an integer                            

    result_array = np.append(result_array, average_int)             # Append average_int into result_array

    peaks_pos = signal.find_peaks_cwt(result_array, range(1, 3))    # Find peaks of result_array
    peaks_diff = peaks_pos[1:] - peaks_pos[:-1]                     # Count the frames between each peak
    peaks_frames = peaks_diff[-1:]                                  # Select counted frame value from end of array

    frequency = 60000/(peaks_frames * 60)                           # calculate beats per minute with 60000ms/(peaks_frames)*60ms

    print(type(average_int))      #class: 'int'
    print(type(frequency))        #class: 'numpy.ndarray
    print(frequency)
    plt.pause(0.00001)

    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
```

The main issue it seems is that when I graph `average_int` it works but when I try to graph `frequency` I get an error. The classes are different and I tried to convert `frequency` into an int or a float but it still has no impact and I get the same error.

Let me know if you want my live graph code lines.

Comment: Where are you making the graph? I don't see anything. It would give some insights. Also how many values are residing inside the frequency *numpy.array*?

Comment: I added the code lines, and there should only be one value each time.

Comment: How exactly are you converting the frequency(which is a list) into and integer like average_int?

Comment: *frequency.astype(int)[0]* This should just give you an integer frequency residing inside your frequency array and things should work.

Comment: average_int gets appended to an empty result_array so I can do a peak analysis on it. I then wanted to change it back to an int so that I could graph it. For example I am able to graph average_int but not frequency

Comment: This is what I am asking. How are you converting frequency(array) into integer like average_int?

Comment: That is where I am stuck, I am trying to convert it to an int. I already tried astype but I get an error that says this: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: Use frequency.astype(int)[0] . *Astype* just give you an array back with integer elements. Picking up the only element will give you a single integer like average_int.

Comment: Sorry, I am only about two weeks into coding so I may be using it wrong. I added the following to my code.

frequency_int = frequency.astype(int)[0]

But I get this error: IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: This error shows that you have an empty frequency array. :/

Comment: When I print frequency I get the following:

[]
[]
[]
[250.]
[100.]

Does that mean I have to fill the first three loops somehow with a zero or something? Edit: not a zero but a random value

Comment: *I added the code lines, and there should only be one value each time*. There are more than one values in this array. I don't know how your algo works. Averaging these values or what or append one by one into some array. Append 0 if an empty array. There can be lots of different ways. depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I may be wrong how it works, but every loop a number is appended to result_array. This array grows and the peak indices are shown for example: [5,15,25] . Then I find the difference using (peaks_pos[1:] - peaks_pos[:-1] ) Which creates the gaps between the indices [10,10]. What I want to do is grab the last position of this growing array and turn it into an int so I can graph it so I want to grab the 10. I try to do this with "peaks_frames = peaks_diff[-1:]" I may have to just try a different method

Comment: if you just want the last value of `peaks_diff`, you should use: `peaks_frames = peaks_diff[-1]` (note there is no colon there). That will give you a single value rather than a length-1 slice

Comment: ^ makes sense to me now :D

Comment: Yes that fixed the problem, thank you. I need to take a week off and just focus on the basics it seems.